# Pivot Table for Java SWT or Swing

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

Is there a Java Pivot Table for SWT or Swing?
This would be to replicate slice and dice in Excel, with a dynamic (constantly updating) data model.

The only one I can find is JIDE, which is a commercial package.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing mysterious in a pivot table - it's just a view on an existing table. With Java, you can achieve the same result by creating a table model which maps coordinates to another table model.

The most simple pivot table just swaps row and column coordinates. The code for `TableModel` would then look:

```
public class PivotTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private TableModel delegate;

    public PivotTableModel (TableModel delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public int getRowCount() { return delegate.getColumnCount(); }
    public int getColumnCount() { return delegate.getRowCount(); }
    public Object getValueAt( int row, int col ) { return delegate.getValueAt( col, row ); }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java Swing, you can use a JTable with an underlying TableModel.

In Java SWT (JFace), you can use a TableViewer with an underlying ContentProvider and LabelProvider.

You would be responsible for maintaining the data model that supports the table.

You would be creating your own pivot table.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the free Java swing component https://github.com/aristsoft/jpivot 
This component just visualize data in multidimentional view, but do not aggregate them itself.

Answer (score 0):

For a commercial pivot table in Java/Swing, you can try Citra Pivot. It can read data from a TableModel, as well as from OLAP databases.

http://www.citra-tech.com/products/pivot.html

Answer (score 0):

NAT Table is available in SWT world. You should try it.

http://www.eclipse.org/nattable/

Answer (score 0):

[jmagallanes](http://jmagallanes.sourceforge.net/en/) opensource pivot table implemented with swing.